# flask-sqlalchemy : how to manage SQL Views?

Tags: python, flask, view, flask-sqlalchemy

I am discovering Flask-SqlAlchemy, and currently facing an issue with the views : how can I properly manage them in the model of SqlAlchemy? Can I differenciate them in the code ?

For example if I have these two SQL Table :

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
  [username] VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  [email] VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC))


CREATE TABLE Address (
  [username] VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  [address] CHAR(58) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([username] ASC, [address] ASC))
```

and the view

```
CREATE VIEW [AccountView] AS
    SELECT [Account].[username]
            ,[Address].[address]
    FROM [Account]
    INNER JOIN [Address] ON [Account].[username] = [Address].[username]
```

In python I have build the two tables like :

```
class Account(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(13), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)


class Address(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(13), primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
```

what is the best solution to create the view model? I have try :

```
class AccountView(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(13), primary_key=True)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
```

But here I don't see how SqlAlchemy can know it refer to a view, and so it is readonly and also should be update if I update Account or Address table.

Any advice here? I am working the right way?

Comment: Have a look to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html

Comment: @BenoîtZu That doesn't seem to be related to views nor to flask-sqlalchemy?